# Setup MongoDB in Synology NAS using Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, synology

I am very new to Synology NAS and docker. I am trying to setup a mongoDB in docker on my Synology and not quite sure how to do it. There are images i am finding but not sure which to choose.

Also once I get that setup I would like to run a node server. How is it that you allow the DB to talk with the node server. I assume the node server is in another container, how do you allow for that communication?